# Looking for a more efficient way of doing this for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

My data set has over 3 million records so this loop is taking forever.

I want to create a bout_len_tracker variable that counts how many consecutive rows for the same SUBJECT have VECTORMAGNITUDECOUNTS >= 1853.

```
sub_study$bout_len_tracker <- 0

for ( i in 2:nrow(sub_study) ) { 
  if ( (sub_study$VECTORMAGNITUDECOUNTS[i] >= 1853) & (sub_study$SUBJECT[i] == sub_study$SUBJECT[i-1]) ) 
    sub_study$bout_len_tracker[i] <-  sub_study$bout_len_tracker[i-1]+1 
  }
```

Comment: Consider parallelizing your code.

Comment: @mhovd Golden rule of sustainable parallelization: 1. optimize slow code 2. if still slow, consider parallelization

Comment: I consider parallelization the poor programmers optimization (but I definitely agree)

Answer (score 1):

You could put `cumsum` of `VECTORMAGNITUDECOUNTS >= 1853` in `ave`. Here an example:

```
dat$len <- with(dat, ave(n >= 10, id, FUN=cumsum))
dat
#    id t  n len
# 1   1 1 17   1
# 2   1 2 18   2
# 3   1 3  5   2
# 4   2 1  5   0
# 5   2 2 17   1
# 6   2 3 14   2
# 7   3 1  1   0
# 8   3 2 15   1
# 9   3 3 20   2
# 10  4 1 10   1
# 11  4 2  7   1
# 12  4 3 18   2
# 13  5 1  4   0
# 14  5 2  4   0
# 15  5 3 15   1
```

If there are `NA`s in `n`,

```
dat$n[sample.int(nrow(dat), nrow(dat)*.2)] <- NA
```

you can expand this to:

```
dat$len <- with(dat, ave(n >= 10, id, FUN=\(x) cumsum(replace(x, is.na(x), 0))))
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), t = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), n = c(17L, 18L, 5L, 5L, 17L, 14L, 1L, 
15L, 20L, 10L, 7L, 18L, 4L, 4L, 15L)), out.attrs = list(dim = c(id = 5L, 
t = 3L), dimnames = list(id = c("id=1", "id=2", "id=3", "id=4", 
"id=5"), t = c("t=1", "t=2", "t=3"))), row.names = c(NA, -15L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is conditional cumsum whereby it reverts back to 0 when the `n<1853`. For example in your case, for ID 1 row 3, len = 0 and not 2. Notice that OP talks about *how many `consecutive` rows of same subject have `n>10`*

Answer (score 1):

library(data.table)

```
setDT(dat)[,tracker:= (n>=10) * rowid(n >= 10),id][]

     id t  n tracker
 1:  1 1 17       1
 2:  1 2 18       2
 3:  1 3  5       0
 4:  2 1  5       0
 5:  2 2 17       1
 6:  2 3 14       2
 7:  3 1  1       0
 8:  3 2 15       1
 9:  3 3 20       2
10:  4 1 10       1
11:  4 2  7       0
12:  4 3 18       2
13:  5 1  4       0
14:  5 2  4       0
15:  5 3 15       1
```

Comment: This gets really close but the tracker doesn't revert back to 0 when n<10 if it's still the same id.

Comment: @Alex  , do you wat to sum the tracker when n<0, also or do you want to maintain them as 0? In your code, you maintained them as 0

Comment: I want to maintain them as 0. In your example, if line 4 had id=1 and n=11, I would want the tracker to be 1.

Comment: @Alex this code does exactly that. Try it out. Try a different dataset eg, instead of having 5 id's have a dataset with 2 ids and see that it will produce the desired results

Comment: I tried it in my data set, and if line 4 in your example had id=1 and n=11, this code sets the tracker to be 3. It's cumulative within the whole group of ids.